# How to add ImageView inside EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-imageview

I have a rounded rectangle `editText`. How can I add the `imageView` inside `EditText` ?

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextDate"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateIcon"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="Date"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/dateIcon"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Before this, I tried

```
 <EditText
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/editTextDate"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

but I can't change the Image color using `android:tint`.

Comment: Kindly share your  output

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya updated

Comment: `android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/` FYI use your custom image instead android default

Comment: `android:drawablePadding="5dp"` used for ? I have used `android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/` before, but I can't change the color. That's why I create `ImageView` and `EditText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the rounded corner rectangle to your EditText Background, use it on the parent RelativeLayout. Make the subsequent children bg transparent:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDate"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateIcon"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Date"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:id="@+id/dateIcon"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method for this.

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
    text.setText("MyText");
    text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null,
                       getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable, null), null);
```

You may also use `android:drawableRight` or `android:drawableLeft`

```
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/my_image"
```

Comment: I have used `android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/` before, but I can't change the color of image, that's why I create `ImageView` and `EditText`

Comment: but why you want to change the color of image ?

Comment: The color is white, I want to change to blue

Comment: for changing image color you can try something like this android:backgroundTint="@color/grey" in your imageview

Comment: But image cannot place inside editText. You can check my first code .  `android:backgroundTint` change my editText background

Answer (score 2):

```
       <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingEnd="60dp"
                    android:paddingStart="4dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_email"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_password"/>

            </FrameLayout>
```

It'll look like this(check image in the link):-
              https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBrjO.png

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/curve_button">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateIcon"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dateIcon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"
        android:tint="@color/red" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**android:background="@drawable/curve_button**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#1a1919" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @JohnJoe happy to help you

Comment: never know that I can set a background for relative layout :P

Comment: @JohnJoe did it help u than please mask my ans accepted thank u

Comment: Subrata M. answer same like you. So I have accepted his answer since he gave the answer first. But I will upvote for sure

Answer (score 0):

[image]

android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
    android:hint="Search for services"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewDescription" />
```